# postgres query to insert data in a table from other table using combination of two common entries of thecolumns in both tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have 2 tables t1 & t2 both containing 3 columns a,b,c the entries in column 'a' and 'b' are same but ordered differently in t1 & t2. I want to use combination of 'a'&'b' entries of t1, and whichever combination matches with t2 enter the respective data in column 'c' of t1 for that combination to t2.

I want it to do on whole column/table in postgres...can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To just understand your requirement. Respective data from which table.column you want to update/select in column "C"?

Comment: *but ordered differently in t1 & t2.* There is no records order in table, a table is unordered heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.c = t1.c
FROM t1
WHERE t1.a = t2.a
  AND t1.b = t2.b
```

Comment: thanks akina.. it worked..after lil changes as i m using postgresql